# Split column into multiple columns mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, csv

My dataframe has a column (numbers_selected) and for each row, it looks like this:

```
1. 6-9-27
2. 2-3-6-8-30
3. 3-11-13-18
4. 3-14-15-17-18-30
5. 3-8-10-12-16
6. 3-7-8-27-29
7. 8-14-21
```

As you can see each row can have different amount of numbers.

What I am looking for is to see if it is possible to create a column for each of these numbers. There will be up to 6 columns as it is not possible to have more than 6 numbers in a row.

At the end, the dataset should look like these:

| 1st Number | 2nd Number | 3rd Number | 4th Number | 5th Number | 6th Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 9 | 27 | Null | Null | Null |
| 2 | 3 | 6 | 8 | 30 | Null |
| 3 | 11 | 13 | 18 | Null | Null |
| 3 | 14 | 15 | 17 | 18 | 30 |
| 3 | 8 | 10 | 12 | 16 | Null |
| 3 | 7 | 8 | 27 | 29 | Null |
| 8 | 14 | 21 | Null | Null | Null |

> bar

The query I am using is:

Select Week, number_selected from x.

Hope you can help me with these, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about a json approach?

```
select week,
    js ->> '$[0]' as num1,
    js ->> '$[1]' as num2,
    js ->> '$[2]' as num3,
    js ->> '$[3]' as num4,
    js ->> '$[4]' as num5,
    js ->> '$[5]' as num6
from (
    select t.*, concat('[', replace(numbers_selected, '-', ','), ']') as js
    from mytable t
) t
```

This works by using string functions to convert the dash-separated string to something that looks like a json array. Typically, `'6-9-27'` becomes `[6,9,27]`. We can then use json accessor `->>` to bring each array element by index.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3f1ddcca454b28a36e3960f19cd29ca0)**:

```
week | num1 | num2 | num3 | num4 | num5 | num6
---: | :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :---
   1 | 6    | 9    | 27   | null | null | null
   2 | 2    | 3    | 6    | 8    | 30   | null
   3 | 3    | 11   | 13   | 18   | null | null
   4 | 3    | 14   | 15   | 17   | 18   | 30  
   5 | 3    | 8    | 10   | 12   | 16   | null
   6 | 3    | 7    | 8    | 27   | 29   | null
   7 | 8    | 14   | 21   | null | null | null
```

Comment: and any way of doing it directly in MySQL? I like your approach but the table has like 500 thousand rows, so it would be very manual to insert all these rows when creating the table

Comment: @JVA: I don't understand your question. This is a pure MySQL query.

Comment: @JVA do you mean you wanted to actually add new columns and set them rather than just returning the split data in a query?

Comment: pre-5.7, without using json: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=b838437685cbd2270debe1810cf7038f

Comment: @JVA: which version of MySQL are you running? `select version()` can tell you.

Comment: @ysth: I reopened the question. You might want to post your suggestion as an answer.